Newb mistake and question
So I withdrew some Tether USDT and sent it to my Pancake Swap account but I can’t see it there. I looked on Etherscan and saw the tokens in my wallet but I have no idea how to retrieve them. I’m really new to this and any help would be much appreciated. I feel like an idiot. Thanks in advance.

Pancake swap is on bsc chain not on ethereum (the last I checked). You must have sent tokens from an ethereum account to another ethereum account. Ethereum and bsc are 2 seperate blockchains.

Thank you. Would you happen to know the next step in retrieving my tokens?

Share the transaction hash
